# Optimizing the composition of two fuctions

Tags: optimization, compilation, compiler-optimization, function-composition

While developing my programming skills, I often run into information along the lines of "Don't chain these functions together.  Instead, use the built-in function that does both much faster."  To use a fake example:

> Use `average(X)` instead of `sum(X)/len(X)`

Is there something that would stop a compiler from recognizing that `sum(X)/len(X)` is the same as `average(X)` and applying the same optimizations?

Or is optimizing compositions of functions analogous to Lisp macros, where you're working on another layer of complexity compared to simply optimizing functions?

Answer (score 1):

- The compiler will only optimize `sum(x)/len(x)` when optimizations are enabled. Optimizations are usually enabled only on release builds, whereas on debug builds we refrain from applying most optimizations so as to not render the code un-debuggable. Therefore, using `average(x)` will save time on your debug builds, which are, incidentally, quite often also your test builds, meaning that your tests will run faster.
- `sum()/len()` will be optimized as `average()` only if the compiler has built-in knowledge of all three of these functions. Note that just because a function is part of the standard library it does not mean that the compiler has built-in knowledge of it. Most likely it doesn't. In the original C language the compiler had built-in knowledge of ***zero*** standard library functions. In the modern day most C compilers provide built-in ("intrinsic") implementations of some functions, but you need to check with your specific compiler.
- For functions that the compiler has no built-in knowledge, the compiler ***may*** inline `sum()`, then it ***may*** inline `len()`, then it ***may*** recognize the emerging code pattern which permits an additional optimization, and perform that optimization, essentially producing an inlined version of `average()`. Note the use of the word "may"; it may happen and it may not happen.
- However, unless the CPU you are targeting has vector instructions, any functions that contain loops may be disqualified from being inlined under certain optimization strategies. For example, it may be that when optimizing for smaller code size a compiler may avoid inlining functions that contain loops. (And optimizations that favor small code size are preferred by many because a) they include many of the optimizations that yield faster code, and b) they result in better CPU cache utilization.)

That having been said, the usual disclaimers apply:

- Do not worry so much about micro-optimizations. The optimizations that really matter tend to be algorithmic or architectural optimizations. Micro-optimizations in the code are usually peanuts.
- Do not optimize anything unless you have sufficient reason to believe that it represents not just overhead but an ***overhead bottleneck***.
- Favor readability over performance whenever possible.

etc.

Comment: In that specific case, "nothing I say will please you" was due to me thinking the question we should be answering was different from the actual one you were answering, so that result was inevitable due to crossed wires on my end. Once I understood the actual question, your answer made sense :P  In other cases, I'll try to keep that in mind when commenting on answers I think could use improvements, and be more specific if I can about improvements I have in mind.  Feel free to ask me in comments to be more specific in future cases if you're not sure what I was aiming at.